# How to get a list of objects that contain another list of objects in EF6

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, webapi

I have 2 entities:

- Books;
- Genres;

They have a many-to-many relationship:

```
public class Book
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Genre> Genres { get; set; }
}

public class Genre
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Book> Books { get; set; }
}
```

The task is to implement a search by genre.

Using a list/array of genre IDs, find all books that contain all the genres in the array.
The result may include books containing other genres, but they must have the requested ones.

Using something like this:

```
var genres = _db.Genres.Where(g => genresIdList.Contains(g.Id)).ToList();
var books = _db.Books.Where(b => genres.All(b.Genres.Contains));
```

Leads to an exception.

Comment: What's the exception?

Comment: @Arian, The exception is too big, so here is the [picture](https://ibb.co/3Ch1zdW)

Comment: @CodeCaster, genresIdList looks like this: { 1, 3, 2 }.
There seems to be no problem with this.

Comment: Remove `ToList()` and query should work. EF Core supports only `Contains` with local collections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to my problem was:

```
var genres = _db.Genres.Where(g => genresIdList.Contains(g.Id));
var books = books.Where(b => genres.All(genre => b.Genres.Contains(genre)));
```

After removing Genre's ToList() and changing the LINQ query a little, the exception disappeared.

Thanks to everyone who tried to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following query:

```cs
var books = _db.Books.Where(b => b.Genres.Any(g => genresIdList.Contains(g.Id)));
```